# Finding the coordinations of n-th tile

Tags: javascript, python, c++, game-development

Lets say I have a group of tiles that have a 1:1 ratio which form a square. So 5x5, 10x10, 500x500, 2000x2000 etc.. How could I find the coordinations of the the nth tile I give? So lets say I want to find the 11th tile in a group of 5x5 tiles. The coordinations would be X=1 Y=3, but how can I find this out through a function?

[image: Image illustrating which tile in a 5x5 grid]

Comment: If you know the size of your square you can use modulo operator to get the X value and the integer division for the Y

Comment: `X = (11-1)%5 + 1 = 1` and `Y = (11-1)/5 + 1 = 3`. The `-1` and `+1` are needed because you are considering 1-indexing and not 0-indexing.

Comment: @Damien hey, thanks for the solution. What about converting x, y and canvas size to nth tile?

Comment: The inverse operation: `Tile = X + 5*(Y-1) = 11`

Comment: @Damien convering the tile to x and y seems to be working but the y is giving a decimal result. Do I round it? Do I floor it? Ceil it?

Comment: No decimal result at all: integer division !! For example, `13/5 = 2` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wish top-to-bottom, left-to-right order, the following transforms are appropriate, all **counted from zero**:

```
Index n to coord:
x = n % w (w is the width of your rectangle in units)
y = n / w (rounding towards zero)

Coord to index:
n = w*y + x
```

If your indices start at 1, you have to replace `n` with `n - 1` everywhere. If you count `x, y` starting with `1`, replace `x` with `x-1` and similarly for `y`. You may have to solve the resulting equation a bit, for example if all your indices start at 1 you'd end up with:

```
n - 1 = w*(y-1) + x-1
```

which solves to

```
n = w*(y-1) + x
```